# Any open source game engines for Android?

Tags: android

Is there any open source android gaming engine ?

Comment: Strongly disagree with close of question -- it has factual answers, as evidenced by those already given, and is useful data to others coming to the site (likely to be asked again).

Answer (score 12):

There is no open source game engine available on Android equal to commercial Unreal Engine or Unity. But you can use different Open Source Projects for little games or applications.

Java 2d Game Engine (as cocos 2d on iphone):

- [AndEgine](http://www.andengine.org/): perfect for a first game

C++ 2d Game Engine:

- [Cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/): cocos2d is a reference on iPhone. If you know it, try this project.

Java 3d Game Engine:

- [libGDX](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/): many parts are native, so it is an efficient **framework** (not engine) for games. There is a backend with OpenGL do develop on your Desktop.
- [jmonkey](http://jmonkeyengine.org/)

C++ 3D engines available on Android:

- [Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org)
- [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/) (Moblox, Air Hockey EM...)
- [Linderdaum](http://www.linderdaum.com) (Linderdaum Puzzle on Google Play)

Ogre3D and Irrlicht aren't well packaged but you can develop games for iPhone and Android devices. Linderdaum is currently available only for Windows and Android.

Comment: 'There is no open source game engine available on Android'. I'm sorry, but I'm voting down for this. There are quite clearly open source game engines for Android. Anyway, Unreal and Unity are definitely **not** open source.

Comment: ok, i'm not clear. The quality of Open Source game engines on Android is far from Unreal or Unity.

Comment: Rokon is dead. The author suggests AndEngine or libgdx (http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/)

Comment: I think Rokon is being resurrected as a layer on top of libgdx. I've personally used libgdx and it's a nice platform for 2D, the 3D parts are not mature.

Answer (score 10):

[The AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/)
[Candroid](http://code.google.com/p/candroidengine/)
[Cuttlefish Engine (Commercial)](http://www.cuttlefishengine.com/)
[Mages (mostly networking AFAIK)](http://code.google.com/p/mages/)

All these from googling 'android game engine'.

Answer (score 2):

There is a list of at least 23 Open Source Android Game Engines here: http://mobilegameengines.com/android/open_source_game_engines

Comment: People don't like when you use this site to advertise.